# Anylogic: Is ther a way to move agents from a pallet rack to another one directly

Tags: anylogic

in rack pick element, the destination can not be a pallet rack, is there a way to send agents directly from one pallet rack to another pallet rack without any point or rectangular nodes (or any other type of destination except pallet rack) between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to do that you need to use the rackStore and select the destination palletRack. It will pick up the agent in the initial pallet rack and move it to the destination pallet rack.

No need to use rackPick, only rackStore.

Comment: It works but because of not using rackPick even though we see agent moving to new rack but previous rack cells did not get empty. How we can solve that.